# Tensorflow Dst tensor is not initialized. When use tf.Saver()

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have got an error when use tf.saver(). 
My GPU is 1080TI which has 11GB, and I do not figure out why using tf.saver can cause this problem, here is the error message:

```
File "<ipython-input-7-138c302de45b>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('H:/embeddings/factor_vae/run_speech_commands.py', wdir='H:/embeddings/factor_vae')

  File "C:\Users\shiyanpei26\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 704, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\shiyanpei26\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 108, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "H:/embeddings/factor_vae/run_speech_commands.py", line 30, in <module>
    factor_vae.train()

  File "H:\embeddings\factor_vae\model.py", line 472, in train
    self.saver.save(sess,self.store_path+self.model_type+str(self.model_num)+'.ckpt')

  File "C:\Users\shiyanpei26\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 1593, in save
    {self.saver_def.filename_tensor_name: checkpoint_file})

  File "C:\Users\shiyanpei26\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 895, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)

  File "C:\Users\shiyanpei26\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1128, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)

  File "C:\Users\shiyanpei26\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1344, in _do_run
    options, run_metadata)

  File "C:\Users\shiyanpei26\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1363, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)

InternalError: Dst tensor is not initialized.
     [[Node: encoder/dense/kernel/_1295 = _Recv[_start_time=0, client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_270_encoder/dense/kernel", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](^_arg_save/Const_0_0, ^save/SaveV2/tensor_names, ^save/SaveV2/shape_and_slices)]]
```

I searched this error and I found it is because there is no enough GPU memory. But my GPU is 1080TI which has 11 GB, and why run the saver can cause this problem?

Here is the code of that part:

```
#config=tf.ConfigProto()
#config.gpu_options.allow_growth=True
gpu_options = tf.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=0.7)
sess=tf.Session(config=config)

sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

#training process, no error, there is too much so I do not show it

self.saver.save(sess,self.store_path+self.model_type+str(self.model_num)+'.ckpt')  #here is the error
```